# In pig script, how to save passed in parameters/arguments

Tags: oozie

In pig script, I know that we can use passed-in parameters like the following:

```
%declare CMD `$mycmd $date`
A = load '/data/mydata/$CMD';
B = filter A by $0>'5';
```

But how can I save the parameters into a file?

Thanks

Comment: what is the case that you want to solve ?

Comment: For example, when I set an argument in workflow.xml, say "<argument>DATE = 20160220</argument>",  how to write a pig statement to STORE this DATE value into an output file.

Comment: this is understand - but why do you want to do that ? can you save for each run all the configuration - you can use shell command instead. if you want to add it as column for each one for the record - it should be simple

Comment: I just want to record/store the DATE value. Do you know how?

Comment: yes , I mention 2 ways to do that

Comment: But I just store this DATE value separately, not with other columns or values